# CSS: HTML height:100% on one page only

Tags: html, css, tags, height

Dumb question with a simple answer, I think.

I am building a site that has a completely different layout on one page from the rest. On one page, the design requires a liquid vertical layout, so I need the following code: `*{height:100%;}`On the other pages I just want the default height.

I tried to add a class to the html tag, which works in the html, but not in the CSS file. I tried:

```
*.myClass
```

and

```
html.myClass
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I can't seem to find any info on this online. Is it even possible to add classes to the html tag?

I am using wordpress, so I can easily check to see which page I'm on and add myClass.

I guess I could also use @import to get a different style sheet based on the page I'm on, but that seems like a longwinded way of doing things.

How can I specify `height:100%` as a value of the html tag on specific pages only?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `.myClass, .myClass body {height: 100%}`?

It is indeed possible to add a class to the `<html>` tag.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/idixu3) ([see code](http://jsbin.com/idixu3/edit))

Comment: Thanks thirtydot! I knew there had to be a simple answer.

Comment: It may as well of course be an id at that point, and not a class.  While HTML5 may have done away with the invalidity of using the class or id attributes on the html element, you can still only have one html element, which means using a class instead of an id is somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, because I just applied this in one of my projects earlier today. :)

```
html,body { 
   height:100%
}
```

If you have pages that require the default height, then don't load this css style. You can place it in a separate CSS file.